# Change the Last Logged In date

Tags: magento-1.7, custom

I'm trying to write a custom password reset script that adds rewards points to the accounts of all those that reset their passwords. A customised link to this will only be sent to the customers that have never logged into their account before (About 900 of them).

I need to know **how to change the customer's last logged in date** so that they can only get the rewards points once. This is the way I make sure that they haven't reset their password before.

```
$logCustomer = Mage::getModel('log/customer')->loadByCustomer($customer);
$lastVisited = $logCustomer->getLoginAtTimestamp();

if ($lastVisited == NULL)
{
  // Reset password
  // Add reward points to account
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the customer logs in, this date will be updated automatically. However, if you need to change this manually you can do so with the following statement:

```
$customerLog = Mage::getModel('log/customer')->loadByCustomer($customer);
$customerLog->setLoginAt('2013-12-31 00:00:00');
$customerLog->save();
```

Comment: I think you should also set the customer id on the `$customerLog` object in case no last log item was found (I think that's what Lutheneior wants to achieve: add an item if no is found). So add `$customerLog->setCustomerId($customer->getId())` before saving the log object. Not sure about setting `visitor_id`.

Comment: Thank you Phil and Mark, both of your inputs helped me figure it out. I had to create the visitor_id as well to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last logged in date by the following code.

```
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$logCustomer = Mage::getModel('log/customer')->loadByCustomer($customer);
$lastVisited = $logCustomer->getLoginAtTimestamp();
$lastVisitedDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $lastVisited);
```

This `$lastVisitedDate` will update automatically by the system whenever the user logged in. S o if you want to keep this value freeze after first login of the user, then you will have to hard-code some value for this.

```
    $lastVisitedDate = '2013-11-11 00:00:00';// the date you want to set.
    $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    $logCustomer = Mage::getModel('log/customer')->loadByCustomer($customer);
    $logCustomer->setLoginAtTimestamp($lastVisitedDate)->save();
```